# Can “ho fatto” mean “I made”?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, phrase-request

I’ve learned the word “fare” as “to make” or “to do”.

If I wanted to say, “I have never made anything with my own two hands”, I think I would say “Non ho fatto niente con i miei due mani”. Does that convey what I’m trying to say accurately? How would a native speaker say it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'd probably say

> Non ho mai fatto niente con le mie mani.

Notice that:

- you had omitted *mai*, that is, “never”;
- it's *le mie mani* (not *i miei mani*) since *mano* is feminine, even though it ends in *-o*;
- in Italian it sounds more idiomatic without mentioning *due*.